# How do I pass SQLite Cursor from MVP Model to View without breaking Presenter?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, mvp, android-cursor, android-mvp

I have an app implementation using the MVP design, and I want to use a SQLlite database to source data data to the UI `View`. I don't want/need to use a `ContentProvider` as the data is only required by my app alone.

I know that the `View` should be 'dumb' and any 'business' logic should go in the `Presenter` and the `Model`. Yet the `Presenter` should contain no Android code in order to allow for standalone unit testing.

So how do I perform the transportation of SQLite data from the `Model` back to the `Presenter` and then the `View` if I can't use a `cursor` in the `Presenter`?

I can use a callback but is the 'correct' way to create my own data structure, load the data into that and then pass a list in the callback?

I'd like to stay true to the `MVP` design.
I've Googled this to death and whilst there's plenty of stuff on handling the `Context` in the `Presenter` there's not a lot about using other Android data structures.

Comment: see https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/deprecated-todo-mvp-loaders/ and / or https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture in general

Comment: and why do you think that using `android.database.Cursor` interface is worse that using `java.util.List` interface (or any other "collection" interface)?

Comment: According to all the guidance I read, I should not be referencing the `android` api, so therefore I shouldn't be using `Cursor`? With reference to the Google Samples, I'm familiar with them, but using a `Loader` would mean writing a `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have SQLite access in the view even in presenter.

All accesses to model are made in model layer, so if you need to interact with that cursor from the view / presenter you will have to create methods to call it:

From View call a presenter method -> From Presenter call model method -> From model call its cursor interaction method.

And viceversa.

So... what you need should be something like this:

View notifies to some presenter method that want some data (presenter.loadInfo(...)) -> Presenter calls the model (UseCase, a model class, etc.) [model.loadData(...)] -> Model has an attribute or gateway to database, so it asks for a query and, once it has de info, it returns to the presenter.

It's expected to be asynchronous, so create a callback and call it from presenter:

```
model.loadInfo(..., new onResponseCallback() {

method onResponse(MyResponseClass response) {

//Manage your response as you want
view.showData(...)

}

method onFailure(MyFailureClass failure) {
view.showFailure...
} 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel I agree with everything you've said. There's no problem calling the SQLite database from the `Model`, or with using callbacks which I do already. My question is more related to the representation of the data I am sending back in my callback. If I pass a reference to the `Cursor`, then I have a dependency on part of the Android API which 'breaks' MVP. I was just interested in how my data should be posted to the `Presenter`/`View`

Comment: Could you share any sample about what's your dependency with the cursor? What's your concrete problem? (The flow, like: I have a list, and i load X elements, and when I scroll i want to load the next X items from the cursor... something like that)